# Relation In Between Models In Yii

Tags: mysql, orm, yii

I have the database like this

```
+------------------+
|     Invoices     |
+------------------+
| id               |
| customer_id (Fk) |
| description      |
+------------------+

+------------------+
|   InvoiceItems   |
+------------------+
| id               |
| Item_name        |
| price            |
| discount         |
| description      |
+------------------+

+------------------+
|    Customers     |
+------------------+
| id               |
| firstname        |
| lastname         |
| description      |
+------------------+
```

According to the database I made relations in the models as follows.
In Invoices model,the relation is like this

```
public function relations()
{
 return array(
  'invoiceitem' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'InvoiceItems','invoice_id'),
  'customers'    =>  array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Customer','customer_id'),
 );
}
```

In InvoiceItems model relation is like this

```
public function relations()
{
 return array(
   'invoice' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Invoices','invoice_id'),
 );
}
```

In Customers model the relations is like this

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
   'invoice' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Invoices','customer_id')
  );
}
```

Now I want to know if the relations between these models are right or not?

Comment: your relations are correct provided you have the foreign key as mentioned by Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Invoice item does not have a field called invoice_id in the table description. The relations need a reference to the primary key to work. The db-field you declare in the relation should contain the primary key of the model you are working with. So if you are working with a invoice, the HAS_MANY relation should be able to find the id of the invoice in the invoice_id field on the item.
You could also use a separate table for the relation data and declare it like:

```
array(self::HAS_MANY,'InvoiceItems',reltable('invoice_id', 'item_id))
```

You can read more about the relations [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply.I forgot to write that invoice_id in InvoiceItems table in my question.Actually I have defined that from my site.Anyway can you tell me is the relation between models are correct?So that I can proceed....